# Is there a way to retrieve Access Log from a biometric device using onvif?

Tags: onvif, python-onvif

I have a simple python program that attempts to retrieve the access logs from the biometric card reader.

The following program managed to retrieve the system log.

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

mycam = ONVIFCamera('192.168.1.108', 80, 'admin', 'password', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wsdl')

tLog = mycam.devicemgmt.GetSystemLog({'System'})

print(tLog['String'])
```

But when i changed the argument string for the GetSystemLog function to 'Access', it still returns me the system log.

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

mycam = ONVIFCamera('192.168.1.108', 80, 'admin', 'password', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wsdl')

tLog = mycam.devicemgmt.GetSystemLog({'Access'})

print(tLog['String'])
```

Can I ask the community how can I retrieve the AccessLog in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: Devices often have poor implementations of ONVIF and do cheap hacks like this just to pass the ONVIF device test suite. Try updating the firmware or contacting the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

The information stored in the System and Access log is not defined by ONVIF. In fact, if you read §8.3.11 of the [core specs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification.pdf?70a948&70a948), you will find this:

> The  exact  format  of  the  system  logs is outside the scope of this standard.

I suspect that you are trying the get the information from an access control device. If this is the case, you should use the correct functions specified by Profile A and Profile C to fetch the information, not point to the log provided by the devices service.